# How to write these patterns?

Tags: regex

How to write these patterns?

1)
[ the/DT$ government/NN ] has/VBZ n't/RB [ any/DT authority/NN ] to/TO issue/VB [ new/JJ debt/N$ obligations/NNS ] of/IN [ any/DT kind/NN ] [ the/DT Treasury/NNP ] said/VBD...

how to get DT$, VBZ, RB, DT, NN...
or the part between '/' and space.

2) This is tagsets for Brown database. Is there a pattern for all tags in this link:
http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/brown.html

Can 1) and 2) be combined as one pattern?

We are new to regex, please help.
Thank you very much.

edit:
1) We want to extract the part between / and space:
for example: This is a section from a corpus with tag, we just want to extract the tag, not word/token. The tagset includes uppercase letters or uppercaseletters+$, as shown below. We want to get only tags. Are we making the question clear? The tag rule is:

uppercase letter or uppercase letters or uppercase letters + $

[ the/DT$ government/NN ] has/VBZ n't/RB [ any/DT authority/NN ]...

How to have a pattern that only extract 
DT$, NN, VBZ, RB, DT, NN..

In other words, we should get part between / and space.

We are using a Tperlregex wrapper that support most functions and patterns.
The reg may be sth like /\w+|$, but we do not know.

We do not know if we have made it clear.

Comment: I do not understand. Please give an example of a real input string, and the array of results you expect in return

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do this in Python?

Comment: Oh. You're trying to pull out noun phrases, like a chunker, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this: "/[A-Z]+\$?\ ". (without qoutes of course)

Comment: And How about this : "/[A-Z]+\$*" or "/\w+\$*".

Comment: And this: "/[A-Z]+\${0-2}" , having 1, 2, or no $

Comment: Well, they all may work. It depends on **what exactly** you a trying to match

Comment: `/[A-Z]+\$*` will match any number of $. `/\w+\$*` will match lowercase letters too. `/[A-Z]+\${0,2}` (note, there should be comma instead of the hyphen) will match zero, one or two $. `/[\p{Lu}]+\$` will match any letter in the unicode uppercase class (it your regelar expression processor supports unicode classes)